# xdg-open not opening an bluejeans

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xdgutils

I'm trying to open BlueJean after a link in my browser. I get prompted if I wanted to let xdg-open open an application for the url, I agree and click the button. However, the right app is not opened and a default app opens up doing nothing. Basically, a new window is opened for my browser as the the link passed is basically an url.

The error shown on console is

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 800: : Permission denied
Opening in existing browser session.
[177214:177214:0224/132020.005501:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
```

I'm not sure what is being denied, everyone has execution access to `/usr/bin/xdg-open` and the application.

```
❱ ls -l /usr/bin/bluejeans-v2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Feb 24 12:31 /usr/bin/bluejeans-v2 -> /opt/BlueJeans/bluejeans-v2
❱ ls -la /opt/BlueJeans/bluejeans-v2 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 114921480 Feb  4 04:51 /opt/BlueJeans/bluejeans-v2
❱ ls /usr/bin/xdg-open -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25621 Jan 11 07:39 /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

I tried stracing the browser when I open it in a shell but nothing useful comes up.

Maybe this would also be useful

```
❱ cat /usr/share/applications/bluejeans-v2.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=BlueJeans
Comment=BlueJeans Desktop App
Exec="/usr/bin/bluejeans-v2" %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=bluejeans-v2
StartupWMClass=BlueJeans
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/bjnb;
Categories=AudioVideo;
```

```
❱ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/bjnb                   
bluejeans-v2.desktop
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happened  was that there was no default application to the mime type, and a default browser was trying to open it.

To solve the problem all I had to do was:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/bluejeans-v2.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

And now `x-scheme-handler/bjnb` would open with bluejeans.