# Permission error in using xdg-open when opening file with registered extension

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mime-types, file-association, xdgutils

I have been trying to perform File Association on Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL2.

1. I have my mime Type specification file at  `/usr/share/mime/packages/application-x-demo.xml`. This is the content of `apllication-x-demo.xml`.

   [image]
2. I have my `.desktop` file at `/usr/share/applications/StartupLinux.desktop`. This is the content of my `StartupLinux.desktop`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=true
   MimeType=application/x-demo
   Name=StartupLinux
   Exec=/home/<user>/MyWorkspace/StartupLinux.sh
   ```
3. If I run the command:

   ```
   gio info myFile.axsd | grep "standard::content-type"
   ```

   ... I get the that my extension is successfully registered with the mime. Command output:

   ```
   standard::content-type: application/x-demo
   ```
4. If I run the command:

   ```
   gio mime application/x-demo
   ```

   ... I get that my application is the default application for the mime type. Command output:

   [image]

**The Problem**: If I try to open my file using xdg-open, I'm getting a permission error:

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 800: : Permission denied
```

I have tried the these links, but did not find any working solution:

- [xdg-open not opening an bluejeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358553/xdg-open-not-opening-an-bluejeans)
- https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x-www-browser-and-xdg-open/17665

Comment: Please try to always include text as text, rather than images.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for why.  Please edit the text in when you get a chance.  Thanks!